# Paradoxical Decomposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

A paradoxical decomposition of a group $G$ is a decomposition of $G$ into disjoint subsets: $G=U\cup S_1\cup S_2\cup\cdots\cup S_m\cup T_1\cup T_2\cup\cdots T_n$ so that there exist elements $g_1, \ldots g_m, h_1,\ldots h_n\in G$ so that:
$$G=\bigcup_{i=1}^m g_iS_i,\text{ and }G=\bigcup_{j=1}^n h_jT_j.$$
(In other words, $G$ can be decomposed into disjoint pieces which can be translated to give two copies of $G$)

Show that $F_2={\left\langle A ,B \right\rangle}$ has a paradoxical composition with $m=n=2$.

In theory this makes sense, but the proof is hard to picture.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint.**  Any element of $F_2$ (thought of as a reduced word on the basis $\{A,B\}$) begins with one of $A$, $B$, $A^{-1}$ or $B^{-1}$.

Comment: Great hint and nice result.:)

Comment: So both the branches that start with $A$ or $A^{-1}$ make up the whole group $G$ that is where I am confused.

Comment: @AllAboutGroups We can write $F_2 = B\mathscr{F}(B^{-1})\cup\mathscr{F}(B)$, and $F_2 = A\mathscr{F}(A^{-1})\cup\mathscr{F}(A)$ where, for $X\in\{A,B,A^{-1},B^{-1}\}$, we define $\mathscr{F}(X)$ to be the set of reduced words in $F_2$ beginning with $X$.

Answer (score 0):

So let $S_i$ be the words generated beginning with $A$ or $A^{-1}$ and let $T_j$ be the words that beginning with $B$ or $B^{-1}$, because $S_i$ and $T_j$ can have two options, both $m$ and $n$ are both $2$?